# Adding ImageButton top of another one in android

Tags: android, imagebutton

I'm making a gallery in my application. I listed my images successfully and now adding its share buttons. Instead of directing user into another form, I'm trying to show share buttons above my image. For listing and sharing I need to create and add dynamic `ImageButtons`. But when I try to **add share buttons**, they're shown in wrong place. Here is my code:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llGallery);
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    final JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    final String Photo= jsonObject.getString("PhotoLink");

    // PhotoDetails into another view
    View.OnClickListener cPhotoDetails= new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(GalleryDetailsActivity.this,
                    GalleryPhotoDetails.class);
            intent.putExtra("Image", Photo);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };

    View.OnClickListener cShare= new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                File myFile = new File(fotograf);
                MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
                String ext = myFile.getName().substring(myFile.getName().lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
                String type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);
                Intent sharingIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.SEND");
                sharingIntent.setType(type);
                sharingIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.STREAM", Uri.fromFile(myFile));
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share with"));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    };

    RelativeLayout rel = new RelativeLayout(context);
    rel.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

    ImageButton img = new ImageButton(context);
    img.setClickable(true);
    img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
    Glide.with(context).load(Photo).into(img);
    img.setOnClickListener(cPhotoDetails);
    rel.addView(img);

    ImageButton share = new ImageButton(context);
    share.setClickable(true);
    share.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    Glide.with(context).load(R.drawable.btn_share).into(share);
    share.setOnClickListener(cShare);
    rel.addView(share);

    ll.addView(rel);
}
```

[image: Gallery]

Comment: Can you please provide an image showing _the wrong place_?

Comment: What's your want and what's the result.

Comment: I've added an image for my request into my post. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use FrameLayout Instead of RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RelativeLayout rel = new RelativeLayout(context);
        rel.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

        ImageView img = new ImageView(context);
        img.setClickable(true);
        img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        Glide.with(context).load(Photo).into(img);
        img.setOnClickListener(cPhotoDetails);
        rel.addView(img);

        ImageButton share = new ImageButton(context);
        share.setClickable(true);
        share.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        Glide.with(context).load(R.drawable.btn_share).into(share);
        share.setOnClickListener(cShare);
        rel.addView(share);

        ll.addView(rel);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It appeared exactly i want.